# Bound on critical points of Lefschetz fibration over the disk with prescribed monodromy

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, mapping-class-groups, contact-geometry

Let $\phi$ be a right-veering diffeomorphism of a surface $\Sigma$ of genus $g$ and $r$ boundary components. Suppose that the diffeomorphism is freely periodic so if $M$ is the associated open book and $L$ is the binding, then $M \setminus L$ is Seifert fibered. Assume that we know that $M$ is Stein fillable. One can also assume that all fractional Dehn twists coefficients are smaller than $1$ to avoid having many critical points corresponding to Dehn twists around boundary parallel curves.

> Is there a known upper bound (depending on invariants of $\phi$ or $M$) on the number of critical points of Lefschetz pencils $X \to D^2$ over the disk with $\partial X = M$ and prescribed monodromy $\phi$?

I am working with the usual definition that a Lefschetz pencil is a map $X \to D^2$ which is locally trivial away from some finite set of critical points $x_1, \ldots, x_{l} \subset X$ all with distinct critical values always not in the boundary. And that the local model for each critical point is that of a Morse point.

First of all, it is not clear at all that such Lefschetz pencils should exist. Since it is not known if all right-veering freely periodic diffeomorphisms admit a positive factorization. So my questions is: should they exist, do such upper bounds exist? (That's why I ask in terms of $\phi$ and $M$).

Some approaches.

In particular it is known that $\chi(X) = \chi(\Sigma) + l$. So an answer to my question would be to provide a upper bound on the possible Euler characteristics of Stein fillings of $M$.

It is also known that in integral homology $H_1(X) \simeq H_1(\Sigma)/\langle c_1, \ldots, c_l\rangle$. Where $c_i$ is a vanishing cycle. So, again, knowing the possible first Betti numbers of the Stein fillings, one may find an upper bound to the number of vanishing cycles of the Lefschetz pencil.

Another approach would be to provide an upper bound on the length of positive factorizations of $\phi$ in the mapping class group of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Just for comparison: if you drop the assumptions on $\phi$, there is no such upper bound. This is proved by Baykur, Monden, and Van Horn-Morris (*Positive factorizations of mapping classes*, Alg. Geom. Topol. 17(3), 2017).

Comment: Yes, I know this work. That's why I put this assumptions on $\phi$. Also, if you try to produce a periodic diffeo with fractional Dehn twist coefficients 1/n. And then prove some lower bound on the number of Dehn twists. And then you try to use that paper to get a contradiction,  you (where you means I) don't get to a contradiction. So, in some sense it looks that it may be true that right-veering periodic diffeomorphisms admit always a positive factorization (maybe using separating curves).